# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked (Redux toolkit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux-toolkit

I am trying to set a state value

[image: 1]

in firebase function. Whenever I try to set I get:

redux.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked
at redux.js:66:1